# PHP: Retrieving instance of class method from another class

Tags: php, wordpress, oop, namespaces

I am trying to bring the WordPress header into my application.
I have this class that connects with Wordpress and extracts the HTML that I need:

```
namespace XLite\Module\Guru\WordPress;

/**
 * Main module
 */
class WordPress extends \XLite\Base\Singleton
{
    /**
     * Get WordPress header and body class
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public static function getWPHeader($element){

        $WP = array();

        require_once(__DIR__ . '../../../../../../../../../wp-blog-header.php');
        $wpHeader = self::ob_get_call('get_header');

        if (!isset($dom)) {
            $dom = new \domDocument;
        }
        $dom->loadHTML($wpHeader);

        //Get body class
        $bodyElements = $dom->getElementsByTagName("body");
        foreach ($bodyElements as $node) {
            $bodyClass = substr($node->getAttribute('class'), 5);
        }
        $WP['bodyClass'] = $bodyClass;

        $headerElement = $dom->getElementById("masthead");
        $WP['header'] = $dom->saveHTML($headerElement);

        return $WP;
    }
}
```

And this code will execute just fine. I am referencing it in another file like this:

```
namespace XLite\Module\Guru\WordPress\View\Header\Customer;

/**
 * Header
 *
 * @ListChild (list="body", zone="customer", weight="10")
 */
class Header extends \XLite\View\Menu\Customer\ACustomer
{
    /**
     * Get WordPress Header
     *
     * @return html
     */
    public function getWPHeader(){
        $wpHeader = \XLite\Module\Guru\WordPress\WordPress::getWPHeader();

        echo $wpHeader['header'];
    }
}
```

And this works! I can echo the header HTML. But I need to access the same class again so I can append the body styles:

```
namespace XLite\Module\Guru\WordPress\View;

/**
 * Replace Body Template
 */
abstract class Controller extends \XLite\View\ControllerAbstract implements \XLite\Base\IDecorator
{
    /**
     * Get WordPress Body class
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getWPBodyClass(){
        $wpHeader = \XLite\Module\Guru\WordPress\WordPress::getWPHeader();

        echo $wpHeader['bodyClass'];
    }
}
```

When both files are active, only one displays the content from the WordPress class. If I comment out or remove either of the viewer classes, the other will show up. I think that I need to only access the class once, and store the data that I need in an instance. But I am really lost, the code is actually more complex, and it is making my head spin. :-) Thanks in advance, I've been lurking on this site for almost 10 years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My great friend Tony Sologubov has answered me via Facebook:
"I believe, the problem is that you are calling WP routines twice. Try to do something like this in your Worpdress class:

```
<?php

// storing wpHeader data in this property
protected static $wpHeader = null;

public static function getWPHeader($element) {
    if (!isset(self::$wpHeader)) {
        // your current implementation of this method
        // save results into self::$wpHeader
    }

    return self::$wpHeader;
}
```

"

He is exactly right, I have implemented his suggestion as follows:

```
protected static $wpHeader = null;

//$wpHeader = $this->getWPHeader();

/**
 * Get WordPress header
 *
 * @return array
 */
public static function getWPHeader(){

    //$WP = array();
    if (!isset(self::$wpHeader)) {
        require_once(__DIR__ . '../../../../../../../../../wp-blog-header.php');

        $wpHeader = self::ob_get_call('get_header');


        if (!isset($dom)) {
            $dom = new \domDocument;
        }

        $dom->loadHTML($wpHeader);

        $headerElement = $dom->getElementById("masthead");

        self::$wpHeader = $dom->saveHTML($headerElement);

        //echo $Header;
    }

    return self::$wpHeader;
}
```

And accessed it the same as above. Thanks Tony!!! I have learned a lot about OOP PHP today because of you.